# Testing on sbt not reading the java.library.path correctly

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

First, I'll list what version of everything I'm using.

```
sbt = 0.13.5
scala = 2.11.1
scalatest = 2.2.0
```

I have a jvmOptions area in my file, where I'm putting a lot of the configuration of the JVM.

```
lazy val jvmOptions = Seq(
  "-server",
  "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=" + java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName,
  "-Dhttps.port=9001",
  "-Xms256M",
  "-Xmx2G",
  "-XX:NewRatio=1",
  "-Xss1M",
  "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M",
  "-XX:MaxPermSize=256M",
  "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC",
  "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC",
  "-XX:+UseParNewGC",
  "-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled",
  "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode",
  "-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing",
  "-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0",
  "-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10",
  "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
  "-Dlogger.resource=custom-logger-settings.xml",
  "-Djava.library.path=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path")
)
```

This supplied the commonSettings area with the correct forks for the run and test.

```
lazy val commonSettings = {
  Project.defaultSettings ++
  ScctPlugin.instrumentSettings ++
  net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings ++
  scalariformSettings ++
  customFormatSettings ++
  unidocSettings ++
  Seq(

    version := PROJECT_VERSION,
    organization := "com.gensler",
    scalaVersion := SCALA_VERSION,

    scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq(
      "-unchecked",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature"
    ),

    parallelExecution in Test := true,
    fork in Test := true,
    fork in test := true,
    fork in testOnly := true,

    javaOptions in run ++= jvmOptions,
    javaOptions in test ++= jvmOptions,
    javaOptions in testOnly ++= jvmOptions,

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % SCALATEST_VERSION % "test" // test framework
    )
  )
}
```

The problem I'm running into is the java.library.path.  I have a third-party library that I'm trying to use that is in my system's java.library.path in the .sbtopts file.

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/teigha
```

That is all that resides in my .sbtopts.  Given everything that's set up, I am getting an error of UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
14:16:49.619 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices - Exception thrown while attempting to load Teigha libraries: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no TeighaJavaDwg in java.library.path
14:16:49.632 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices - Value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/joshadmin/Workspace/avro-nodejs/avrocpp/lib/
14:16:49.632 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices - Value of java.library.path:
14:16:49.633 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /home/joshadmin/Workspace/avro-nodejs/avrocpp/lib/
14:16:49.633 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
14:16:49.634 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
14:16:49.634 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
14:16:49.635 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
14:16:49.635 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /usr/lib/jni
14:16:49.636 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /lib
14:16:49.636 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.g.t.t.custom.CustomSystemServices -      /usr/lib
```

I don't know if this is because I haven't set something right, or if new versions of SBT and Scalatest are doing something I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `javaOptions` in `Test` configuration and not `test` task.

```
javaOptions in test ++= jvmOptions
```

should be

```
javaOptions in Test ++= jvmOptions
```

Note capital `T`.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't notice that it needed to be capitalized.